# Handle stack overflow exception in a endless recursive call

Tags: java, multithreading, recursion

I have a situation like below

```
class a{
    public void process(){
      System.out.println("ABC");
      process();
    }
}
```

while I'm executing at certain point I'm getting stack overflow exception. On my situation I can't change the recursive call logic. So for a work around I try to catch the error and made a gc call again initiate the `process()` method. Whether is it a good solution... or what is the better solution to keep the recursive call alive infinitely.

Comment: This doesn't make sense - what could possibly be the use-case for an infinite recursion?

Comment: In Java, the common answer to this problem is unfortunately "Don't have this problem", i.e. eliminate recursion or use a Stack manually.

Comment: i need to check certain values on endless manner. inside the process method performs a huge validation process in a legendary application....

Comment: Please suggest some example of manual stack... what happens if i catch the stackoverflow error and call the gc

Comment: @tilpner - An explicit stack will not be much help for an infinite recursion...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: Actually, in this case it would. Since there's no information to be preserved, you'd never push anything, and therefore not need an infinite stack. I was mentioning the Stack for the general case though, converting any recursive function into an iterative version.

Comment: @Ramakrishna dont *catch* the stack overflow error, **prevent** it!

Comment: In Java, Errors including `StackOverflowError` or `OutOfMemoryError` can't be caught.

Comment: @mehdi It's a really bad idea, but perfectly possible - not much you can do though particularly in case of a stack overflow

Comment: @Voo Thank you. You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive call uses up a stack frame in the JVM each time recursion occurs, making a stack overflow error inevitable.

The best solution in Java is to use iteration instead.  For example:

```
public void process() {
    while (true) {
        processOnce();
    }
}
```